# Should I annotate Spring Data Repositories with @Repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

For example:

```
public interface CommentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Comment,Integer> {}
```

It works fine with or without @Repository, so should I use @Repository for Spring Data Repository and what is the difference between them?

```
@Repository
public interface CommentRepository extends
PagingAndSortingRepository<Comment,Integer> {}
```